# CocoaPods install doesn't install pods

Tags: macos, terminal, cocoapods

I'm in terminal and I've "installed Cocoapods" however when I go to list the pods it retrieves nothing.

```
XXX-MBP:Desktop XXX$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
1 gem installed
XXX-MBP:Desktop XXX$ pod list

0 pods were found
XXX-MBP:Desktop XXX$
```

Then when I go to search for a particular pod it goes into repo mode and stops.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sudo` is the usual suspect - don't `sudo gem install` stuff and then expect everything to work smoothly..

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: well, install cocoapods without `sudo`